# Replace Artin stack with a scheme with the same cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth proper Artin stack over a perfect field $k$. Suppose there is a finite group $G$ acting by $k$-automorphisms on $X$.

Can we always find a smooth proper scheme $Y/k$ on which $G$ acts by $k$-automorphisms such that $\oplus_{i\geq 0} H^i(X, \overline{\mathbb{Q}_l})\cong \oplus_{i\geq 0}H^i(Y, \overline{\mathbb{Q}_l})$ as $G$-modules for almost all primes $l$?

Comment: This would imply $H^i(X)=0$ for all but finitely many $i$, which is unlikely, if $X$ is genuinely Artin (as opposed to Deligne-Mumford, say). If $X$ is Deligne-Mumford, we could hope that the cohomology of $X$ (or rather its Chow motive) is a direct factor of the one of some $Y$.

Comment: As Denis-Charles says this fails e.g. for the classifying stack of an elliptic curve, whose cohomology is infinite dimensional. Moreover its cohomology fails the Deligne weight bounds for the cohomology of a smooth proper scheme, which gives a second reason for failure. But it's true that the Chow motive of a smooth proper DM-stack is the direct factor of a Chow motive of a smooth proper variety; this follows from de Jong's theorem on alterations and is explained in a paper of Toën "On motives of Deligne-Mumford stacks".

Comment: What happens for $k=\mathbf{F}_p$, $X = B(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}) = [{\rm pt}/(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})]$ and $G$ the trivial group?